# Backup Event Logs via Powershell and WMI

Tags: powershell, wmi, scheduled-tasks, windows-server-2008-r2

I have Powershell script that makes backups of all Event logs on current localhost.

It runs from Task Scheduler with "Run with highest privileges" under restricted account (this account only has Backup Operator rights). Script itself can be found [here](http://lab.technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd822908)

OS: Windows Server 2008 R2, UAC is turned off.

The problem appears in the following line:

```
$Eventlogs = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NTEventLogFile -ComputerName $computer
```

In returned collection of Event logs **Security log is missing** and as result isn`t backuped. All other are present.

If the same script is run directly from Powershell using the same account - Security log is present.
Granting local Admin rights to account solves the issue but isn`t applicable.

Do you have any ideas what may be causing such behaviour? Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

I have not done a lot of research on this but I once encountered a similar problem. Using the switch `-EnableAllPrivileges` in the first call of `get-WmiObject` solved it for me.

Comment: Tried this but unfortunately it hasn't worked. Also tried to explicitely define `-Impersonation Impersonate` switch - also no effect